# Xamarin.Forms DateTime OnPropertyChanged

Tags: datetime, datepicker, inotifypropertychanged

I am just getting my head around all things C# and Xamarin. I have managed to get the OnPropertyChanged working for a string (with a lot of help from StackOverflow), but how do I set it for a DateTime property.

I use this for a string:

```cs
private string _myString;
public string MyString
{
    get { return _myString; }
    set
    {
        if (value.Equals(_myString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }
        _myString = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

obviously the following line is not going to work for DateTime

```cs
if (value.Equals(_myString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

What do I use instead?

thanks in advance

Comment: You probably don't need this check at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
DateTime.Compare(value, _myDate) == 0
```

[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thankyou all for the replies - Barry's works exactly how i need it to

Answer (score 1):

Or just

```
if (value !=_myDate) {...}
```